# Sample and hold - LTI filter

Tags: sampling

I've found a material explaining the sample and hold operation pretty well, but there's one thing I can't understand.

http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781848001183-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-484012-p173780368

*Next, we would like to take this ideally sampled signal and hold the values
between samples. As we have a train of impulses with the correct areas, we
need a “block” that takes an impulse with area A, transforms it into a rectangular
pulse of height A that starts at the time at which the delta function is
input to the block, and persists for exactly Ts seconds. **A little bit of thought
shows that what we need is a linear, time-invariant (LTI) filter whose impulse
response, h(t), is 1 between t = 0 and t = Ts and is zero elsewhere.***

How do we know this is the impulse response that will give us a pulse of HEIGHT A, not area A? Could anyone explain this "a little bit of thought" part? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's sad to see, as late as 2008, that some author is **still** confused about the role and functions of the Sample-and-Hold (a device that sometimes precedes an A/D converter in the signal path) and the Zero-order Hold which is a **hypothetical** device (which is LTI) that is needed to model the hold state of a conventional D/A converter between sample instances. The author, S. Engelberg, is mistaken and repeats a mistake that was in early textbooks on DSP. Sample-and-Hold (S/H) is not the same as Zero-order Hold (ZOH).

Answer (score 2):

An impulse of "area" $A$ means $A\delta(t)$. The nomenclature arises because
$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty A\delta(t) \,\mathrm dt = A,$
that is, the "area under the curve" is $A$.

Since the system is linear and
time-invariant, and the response to input $\delta(t)$ is a pulse of height $1$
and duration from $0$ to $T_s$, the response to $A\delta(t)$ is a pulse of
height $A$ and duration from $0$ to $T_s$.  Its "area" is $AT_s$, that is, $A$
**multiplied by** the area $T_s$ of the response to the unit impulse.

Answer (score 0):

Some little bits of thought:

- the system behaves constantly at any time, turning an impulse into a rectangle => it is time invariant. One can also say that the system needs to transform an impulse into a rectangle but does not now when it will arrive;
- linear, because if two impulses are superimposed then the heights will be added, not mixed or masked in any other way;
- the time range between t and Ts should be obvious;
- the desired output is the height of the impulse (which carries the information), but this value needs to be kept during a certain amount of time Ts to be able to be observed. Thus, what the sample-and-hold should output is a rectangle height A and width Ts. The sample part needs to detect the amplitude A of the signal, while the hold part need to maintain it during Ts seconds.